# SAFE levels in JRuby

Tags: java, security, jvm, jruby, sandbox

Are SAFE levels supported in JRuby? If not, is there other ways of safely running user supplied code in server?

Comment: I added some tags so that the question shows up in the JVM security area, in the hopes that someone much more qualified than me will take a stab at answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, they aren't supported.

The main problem is that they are *very badly* documented, so how are the JRuby developers supposed to provide a compatible implementation if nobody knows what a compatible implementation *is*?

Another reason not to waste time implementing `$SAFE` levels in JRuby, is that the JVM's security mechanisms provide better protection anyway. Which is also the answer to your second question: from the point of view of the JVM, your Ruby script is just another Java program and it can be sandboxed and controlled just like any other Java program.

*How* to do that, however, is a question for a Java expert. I'm just a lowly Ruby hacker …

Comment: $SAFE and the JVM security are completely different concepts.  $SAFE is all about stopping taint/sink based attacks by looking at where user supplied data is coming form. A JVM is a padded room,  a room where you can still get pwn3d with SQL Injection.